# Well-posedness of linear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Is there any reference that explicitely comments on the well-posedness (existence of unique solution) for a PDE of the form?

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}v(s,x)+\varepsilon u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(s,x)-\xi\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}v(s,x)=f(s,x)\\
v(0,x)=g(x)& \forall x\in[a, b]\\
v(s,a)=h_a(s), v(s,b)=h_b(s) &\forall s\in[0,T]
\end{cases}$$

for some functions $g,h_a,h_b$ that prescribe the boundary conditions on a truncated space. I have the impression that most books just take most equations as granted without any further thoughts on well-posedness.

Comment: In the case of a linear, inhomogeneous convection-diffusion equation, uniqueness would follow from assuming two solutions $v_{1}, v_{2}$ satisfy the problem and applying the energy method. Existence would then follow by solving the PDE, usually via separation of variables.